# Delete all files but keep the newest one(s)

Tags: php, delete-file

I have several (archived) backup files in a directory; filenames starting with "backup-".

I want to delete all files which are older than, let say 7 days, but there should always be one file left (the newest), otherwise I do not have a backup file anymore.

I have source code (see below) which will delete ALL files older than 7 days, but how to always keep the newest file in the directory? So, the one left can be older than 7 days (if that is the newest).

```
$bu_days=7;
$files="backup*.tar.gz";

foreach(glob($filter) as $fd) {
  if(is_file($fd) && time() - filemtime($fd) >= $bu_days*24*60*60) {unlink($fd);}
}
```

Comment: Just count your files and break; the foreach when there is just 1 file left ?

Comment: You will have to do some testing before deleting anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your files by date, then delete all but the first:

```
$bu_days=7;
$files="backup*.tar.gz";

//retrieve all files
$theFiles = glob($files);

//combine the date as a key for each file
$theFiles = array_combine(array_map("filemtime", $theFiles), $theFiles);

//sort them, descending order
krsort($theFiles);

//remove the first item
unset($theFiles[0]);

foreach($theFiles as $fd){
    if(is_file($fd) && time() - filemtime($fd) >= $bu_days*24*60*60) {unlink($fd);}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Veve, I think there is a small error in your source:
you forgot the $ (before theFiles) in "foreach(theFiles as $fd){".

Comment: in stead of "first=true" etc you can use "unset(array[0])", which will remove it from the array

Comment: @ni_hao You're right, I've edited my answer with your tip and a better solution which doesn't require to access the file date multiple times for each file.

Comment: Thx again. In the meanwhile I want to be more flexible by not only keep the first file, but to define how many files always should be kept. I also changed (cosmetic) your 'array_combine' line and I prefer more to work with arrays, which brought me to the renewed source

Comment: Appreciated your help. Renewed Source posted above (2 Answers)

Answer (score 0):

Renewed source:

```
//declare after how many days files are too old
$bu_days=7;

//declare how many files always should be kept                              
bu_min=3;

//define file pattern
$files="backup*.tar.gz";

//retrieve all files
$theFiles = glob($files);

//combine the date as a key for each file
$theFiles = array_combine($theFiles, array_map("filemtime", $theFiles));

//sort array, descending order (newest first)
arsort($theFiles);

//return subset of the array keys
$f = array_keys($theFiles);

// keep the first $bu_min files of the array, by deleting them from the array
$f = array_slice($theFiles, $bu_min);

// delete every file in the array which is >= $bu_days days
foreach($theFiles as $fd){
  if(is_file($fd) && time() - filemtime($fd) >= $bu_days*24*60*60) {unlink($fd);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = array_keys($theFiles);
$f = array_slice($theFiles, $bu_min);
```

`$f` should be `$theFiles`